# Why Lua is better for game developement than the iPhone Quartz framework?

Tags: iphone, lua, quartz-graphics

I have seen lots of information about the Lua scripting language for game developement, but I don't understand why it's more powerful than the Quartz framework.

What functionality does Lua give that Quartz does not?

Comment: Do you mean Quartz, the OSX drawing layer, or Quartz, the Java job scheduling framework?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lua is a scripting language. It is used for high level scripting in games (eg. scripting AI, spawning enemies, etc.)
Quartz is the graphics rendering layer in Mac OS. It is used for rendering graphics.
They serve completely different purposes and are often used together.